# Using if/else nested within a for loop in order to cycle through & reassign values within a column in R?

Tags: r

I know that this is not the most efficient way in order to achieve my goal; however, I am using this as a teaching moment (i.e., to show that you can use a if/else statement nested within a for loop). Specifically, I have a nominal variable that uses integers as of right now. I want to use the if/else combined with the for loop in order to reassign these numbers to their respective category (class character). I have tried to do this in multiple ways, my current code is as follows:

```
# Take the original data and separate out the variable of interest
oasis_CDR <- oasis_final %>% select('CDR')

# transpose this data 
oasis_CDR <- t(oasis_CDR)

# create the for loop
for(i in seq_along(oasis_CDR)){
  if(i == 0.0){
    oasis_CDR[1, i] <- "Normal"
  } else if(i == 0.5) {
    oasis_CDR[1 ,i] <- "Very Mild Dementia"
  } else if(i == 1.0){
    oasis_CDR[1 ,i] <- "Mild Dementia"
  } else if(i == 2.0){
    oasis_CDR[1 ,i] <- "Moderate Dementia"
  } else if(i == 3.0){
    oasis_CDR[1 ,i] <- "Severe Dementia"
  } else{
    oasis_CDR[1 ,i] <- "NA"
  }
}
```

When I look at oasis_CDR it returns 'NA' for all observations.

If i replace 'i' with 'CDR' in each 'for' statement it only returns with 'Normal'.

Is there any way that this can be done in order for the reassignments in order to match what the data is?

Comment: The data set I am using is made freely available by the Washington University Alzheimer’s Disease Research Center, Dr. Randy Buckner at the Howard Hughes Medical Institute (HHMI)( at Harvard University, the Neuroinformatics Research Group (NRG) at 
Washington University School of Medicine, and the Biomedical Informatics Research Network (BIRN). It can be found at (https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/mri-and-alzheimers). I only removed the rows with NAs prior to the above code (thus creating 'oasis_final')

Comment: As said below, seq_along returns integers `1:length(oasis_CDR)`. So you will never get an `i = 0.5`.

Comment: Second, you are doing `oasis_CDR <- t(oasis_CDR)` which turns the data into a vector. So referencing oasis_CDR[1,1] is meaningless. It's not a dataframe or matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Run a check on your `seq_along(oasis_CDR)` expression! These will be your `i` values.
My guess is that you do not really want to compare 0.0, 0.5, 1 and 2 against 1 up to > 220, do you?
And if you really wanna work through this via a `for` loop and not with indexing the vector then
isn't it more likely that you want to achive something like this:

```
oasis_CDR$result <- NA_character_
j <- 1
for (i in oasis_CDR) { 
 if (i == ...) oasis_CDR$result[j] <- 'Normal'
... 
j <- j + 1 
}
```

But imho that can get the job done but is not (very) nice R (or any other similar language) code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a different value to assign to every number you can use `dplyr::recode`

```
library(dplyr)

oasis_CDR <- oasis_CDR %>%
                 mutate(new_col = recode(CDR, `0` = 'Normal', 
                                              `0.5` = 'Very Mild Dementia', 
                                               `1` = 'Mild Dementia', 
                                               `1.5` = 'Moderate Dementia', 
                                               `3` = 'Severe Dementia', 
                                               .default = NA_character_))
```